# Methods to add PHP variables into JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In `experience.php`, I have variables that are getting data from ACF, for example:

`$description = get_field("desc");`

What I'm looking to do is to (on click of a button), get the data from the `post` and open it in a modal.

**Pseudo of what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
(function($) {
  $(document).on("click", '.trigger', function(e) {
    console.log($description);
  });
});
```

At the moment, I have the `script` in my php file which I know is incorrect (as PHP is server side and JS is client side). But, I haven't came across a way to do what I'm looking for neatly?

**My approach so far (experience.php):**

```html
<?php $string = "this is a test string"; ?>

<a class="trigger">
  Click me
</a>


<script>
  (function($) {
    $(document).on("click", '.trigger', function(e) {
      console.log("<?php echo $string ?>"); // doesn't work
      console.log("test"); // doesn't work
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your outer most function is not being invoked.  You're a `()` short of it being an IIFE

Comment: `(function($){ ... }(jQuery))`

Comment: Your console.log isn't working which means its. not related to calling PHP variables into JS. Its how you implemented the document ready function. Have a look at this: https://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/ for clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the string. Also, you need to add brackets to invoke your anonymous function.

```
  (function($) {
    $(document).on("click", '.trigger', function(e) {
      console.log("<?php echo $string ?>"); // doesn't work
      console.log("test"); // doesn't work
    });
  })(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo, but I believe that's not the issue, because my `console.log("test");` doesn't work either, it's like the script in the php isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes around PHP output, otherwise it's treated as normal JS code and will throw error about undefined variables:

```
console.log("<?= $string; ?>");
```

---

Your `console.log("test");` does not work, because previous line throws error and halts further execution. Try switching these two lines places.

---

If you ever need to output object to JS variable, then there is no need for quotes:

```
let fooBar = <?= json_encode(["a" => 1, "b" => 2]); ?>;
// let fooBar = {"a":1,"b":2}; - visible in page source code
```

Comment: Ridiculously bad practice echoing PHP values into hardcoded JavaScript variables output by PHP.

Comment: @Undefined Usually you use HTML along side some templating tool, but still have PHP and HTML mix. E.g. Twig, Blade, even Wordpress